# How to get type checks on a computed property?

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to  get type checking on computed property?

Both of the fields have the same interface

```
interface Movie {
  id: number;
  field1: {
    items: string[];
  };
  field2: {
    items: string[];
  };
}

interface State {
  movies: {
    [movieId: number]: Movie;
  };
}

const field: "field1" | "field2" = "field1";

const movieState: Movie = {
  id: 1,
  field1: {
    items: ["1"]
  },
  field2: {
    items: ["2"]
  }
};

function reducer(): State {
  return {
    movies: {
      1: {
        ...movieState,
        [field]: {
            items: ['1'],
            bad: 'bad', // error ?
        }
      }
    }
  };
}
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIHsBuwUG8BQyywAJgFzIgCuAtgEbQDchyMOANiQIwUFFHBINAM4VhYKKADmAbQC6zIgF9FrDiQBMvFgKGjk4ySFkKWK-Evz5QkWIhQBlMHEjI+yGlhz73RGZ+wIAElySloGKDkKDEDVc0t8BHQQcTUITgoAIjZ07kzkAB9kbPUNfIBeYpzOLkzmROTUgJwnFwhorxRK91IKLgAaFmrubX5iPQoZTNq5M0GiYa03HXGIEUnMstnlC3qYKhAEMGBk5CgIEiokKAAKAEoKVtd3c7AqKBBlseaIHxWiHhfMb8AB0YJ+Twg82BfmGUSBMLGgjW+hkAHIuGi5NDEfw6HBQmj8SQ0f1kAB6cnIaBQdBQZAAfn+-EsMNZLLMzCUQA)

Comment: Looks like a [reported issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32236); it's currently not listed as a bug yet, so if you care about it you might want to go to that issue, give it a  and/or describe your use case if it's more compelling than whats there.  Not sure if this counts as an answer for you or if you want something else.  I'll write it up as an answer if it meets your needs; good luck!